# "Missing" questions on Stack Overflow: Page Not Found

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

A search for "type-punned" on Stack Overflow takes me to the URL

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=type-punned

Which lists a question "strict aliasing" and provides the link

[Performance benefits of strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754929/strict-aliasing)

but that link just gets me a message from Stack Overflow:

“Sorry, that page doesn't exist!”

Other questions still "exist" but this one persistently doesn't.

So, is this a bug? Poorly explained feature?

Comment: I voted to undelete it because I see no reason as to why it was removed.

Comment: (undeleted; see answer for details)

Answer (score 3):

The question was deleted on July 8th.  References to it are still lingering though.

If you have 10k rep you can still see the question.

Comment: OK, in that case it seems like a bug that you can still get handed it as a "search result" ten days later. Maybe it's a hard to fix bug, but it's a bug.

Comment: BTW I don't have 10k rep on Stack Overflow yet. Could take me a few years at my current rate. :)

Comment: There is no hurry.  It isn't that special...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user that created it was "destroyed", which deletes any questions / answers / comments etc that they've made.

The question itself seems sound; undeleted.

Update... hmmm; it looks like it may have been me that destroyed the user... I'm 100% confident that I had a good and valid reason... no idea what it was, though.

From the logs:

> Marc Gravell -> Moderator destroys user for id = [redacted] by Marc Gravell - Jul 8 at 7:58